# VK API wall.get() пустой ответ

Tags: android, android-vksdk

Пытаюсь получить текст поста VK.

```
VKRequest request = 
 VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-****,VKApiConst.EXTENDED,0,VKApiConst.COUNT,1,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"text"));                                

request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

@Override

    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

        VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>) response.parsedModel;

       VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);

       Log.d("Post:", post.toString());

       String textpost = post.text;

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.myText);

        textView.setText(textpost);

    }

});
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
05-12 18:18:43.129 8865-8865/checker.news.vk.vknewschecker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: checker.news.vk.vknewschecker, PID: 8865
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiModel com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKList.get(int)' on a null object reference

at checker.news.vk.vknewschecker.MainActivity$2$1$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:130)

at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$3.run(VKRequest.java:482)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Схожий запрос

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));
```

проходит без ошибок.

Как я понимаю, запрос на посты приходит пустой.

Проверил параметры на https://vk.com/dev/wall.get, там ответ есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете параметр `VKApiConst.FIELDS`. В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get) написано: `Обратите внимание, этот параметр учитывается только при extended=1`. У вас же он равен нулю.
Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
VKRequest request = 
 VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-****,VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1,VKApiConst.COUNT,1,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"text"));
```